# Transition not working while transform triggers anyway

Tags: html, sass, css-transitions

What I'm trying to achieve is obviously animate some stuff and it's kinda happening, but without the animation itself. The images just flip no matter what the transition duration is. SASS is kinda new to me, so I guess the problem is laying somewhere in nesting or something.

Here's my HTML

```
    <div class="skills">
        <span class="introduce"> Animations are cool, yay </span>
            <ul class="skills-list">
                    <li class="skill-item"> <img src="images/html5-logo.png">  </li>
                    <li class="skill-item"> <img src="images/css.png">  </li>
                    <li class="skill-item"> <img src="images/sass.png">  </li>
                    <li class="skill-item"> <img src="images/js.png">  </li>
                    <li class="skill-item"> <img src="images/jquery-logo.png">  </li>
                    <li class="skill-item"> <img src="images/pigeon.jpg">  </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

And SASS

```
.skills
  margin: 20px 0 0 0
  padding: 0
  font-size: 18px

  >span
    font-size: 20px

.skills-list
  list-style: none
  color: $main-text
  display: flex
  align-items: center
  justify-content: center
  li
    text-align: left
    padding: 2px
    >img
      height: 165px
      margin-right: 4px
      transition-duration: 5s
      -webkit-transition-duration: 5s
      -webkit-transition-property: all
      transition-property: all
    &:hover
      -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add `transition` to `img` element but apply `transform` to `li` element on hover. If you want to aminate images, your code should look like (apply `transform` to `img` too):

```
.skills-list
  ...
  li
    ...
    >img
      ...
      transition-duration: 5s
      transition-property: all
      &:hover // ->
        transform: rotate(180deg)
```

[Link](http://codepen.io/3rdthemagical/pen/XKGdVo) to working codepen.